# Selenium on Linux Not Allowing Negative set_window_position

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, linux-mint

I have python script that launches several windows, and tiles them using set_window_position and set_window_size. However, if I try to move the windows beyond the desktop (i.e. have a negative x or y using set_window_position) this gets translated into zero.

Example - I initiate:

```
driver.set_window_position(0,-50)
```

And the window moves to the top of the screen but not beyond. 
Checking with

```
driver.get_window_position()
```

results in

```
{'x':0,'y':0}
```

I get the same results with both Chrome and Firefox. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon, Selenium 3.9.0, Python 3.5.2, ChromeDriver 3.25 (with Chrome 64) or geckodriver 0.19.1 (with FireFox Quantum 58). I've tried to disable Window Tiling in Mint and other window effects to no avail. I've also tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 with Selenium 3.9.0 and ChromeDriver 3.25 (with Chrome 64).

However, on Windows 10 with Selenium 3.9.0 and ChromeDriver 3.25 (with Chrome 64) it works as expected - the browser window moves to the negative values and is positioned appropriately.